# Get query response time/duration in react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, time, react-query

I am using react-query's [useQuery](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery)

I need to know **how much time elapsed between when the query was sent and when the query settled**.

I can't find my way using the return type or params of `useQuery`

It's not for debugging purposes but for functional purposes (debugger doesn't help here)

Comment: Is an approximation acceptable? I'm not sure a precise value will be possible because the hook doesn't expose that information (and its operation is async anyway).

Comment: I need a precision of less than a second if possible but any idea or suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer, and the precision should only be off by a factor of a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example which includes a custom hook for measuring the duration that each query is in the `"loading"` state. It includes some comments, and I can explain further if anything is unclear.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEEEBMEMAcBcCmlQDMBOB7AtqAFvPLAM4BcI6i0AxvALQCOArougJ4B080Adsd9QDWHajmCYAbqwkBLRAHcAxIh6YmAczx1uAG0F1ieTPLrZEBnOdGRz0HZWiQ2AWABQbmdliZ08UACUqWgARAHkAWTQsXAByB1o6SBwYgG4PLx8-AG9QG1RoJh0-aGIAoPgAGlAmYkQAUVRURFoqmsRwxGxMVtrA1B7EAGVuJFAAXyicUDjy1PTvX1AcgEUWdgBhHTkeStBV1jZN7fgABSxZG3QB-fYq+DZYRFAAVVqbtkDiQr8JjCmZmj0ZgHObuVyiPh+YEbLYqPwAXlAPAUezWh1hOwAFABKNJgkpsHjUNBMInwGSYHhoRDwah4ADiMngAAkmAAjQLeYLQbigTFtdCkUD8dAyHjqKqUbxCkVi9TYpZuUCgSjwJjoKmY6DyaBM6m0vCYgAGBCIZBAcBkHHUTLw7JEYilmGIwAAJFkBWM3VknWMjdjsRwAFbESk4vFjNxuVCk2gUqlNA2czCBQHvPkKrJKlU09UJml0xks9nJ7ncTExbg8ZHoLZ8HSINgxKoAhLQpu4txjPHR2Pkym5RA6aBsPnYMhIpjYNmsTPZ1V5pEos44GS1TGUUM6KSgeEAPmFNIAKp5EGp4BvEFupFVxwGI1HXCBQEe8GvQJSnvIZDodKA7DqbClDOoAHgATAADFB45uASRIkmS8b6nSyZHg8QzUKKCAZoqrjKhC-C5Dy0C7shDJMqyHKIFyxEVtgMiYc6mCoPAzbTGhjyDJhMgIDEnZ4f+Op6jYw5sJikFQfxyoLhqRHcA+YLAAAVEpSpKaA9I0rk6o8khzGgNQ6qUDsoDtqAYqgPRv5rs0lKQMQallGqGqlEaACSPCoGKTJsEaoDyG+DagDomCOHKanAL2iEDm07wnmYfLtgA0o2MrwKK4pVPwPI1EKryIO8nzfAA2jE2VqsQMQALrYkKPBTjO6C4fhlKEcO-ApR8iCoKRbR9BWAD6A3eeSdh8XiLWQqAxVikg6ASHYWU0h5c0LToVW9bUww8ogAA8xUzjaPB1Q1rBVCokAndOrBVXumLFRBVQeV5PA+TVPYCTJVJtB0XSYjiu4HlmAnKjIPWYu18CdX0IhGXCoAAITwoiyWNnOIPKsFJRQ42MOGegxkIqZaKdRNmPKrU8ArdIdj3Y9oDPSNbDvdmyqRmC5MEX4B2IEd508JAG2IrNNM6B95Ng3yh0WcjiIQaAABkCvCiMNS7sj0whWF4p8c15OHlTOyi-9xX84LCr7tNjzoKgPjYLw1CIBwqjyDiZssxj7Os+Z4MIwAcqd6AcGuABiI2IJiF0Kkr00xKwWDoGxZVMNQjvEJVVXB0SOhMDYxCYuVNQBnr5OU9T820-d0s8DVgPTdXVTW7b6D20STsuziHvk17GNfaAF2gHQoDV2TYxVDNRsVzoWWq8QVSo8z-E9zG0VUnUAAe0BeA2APA5NhHFcVC-z2iIc10t8DvJ14AC2fQvVFtIx7cVsqZThlsrvRtS7bwbB7rd91WxAjRGxRMKFqIpnKO8D22YuZLHMsQAAMqFSAcpzoEx8FUGA3AZ45VKBMREsU0SYmPsTA4Z8pIGValCNE8UniELeLQ08JCSaNlwRVfi2Y2gNCaLQf6Fsgbe2fOsPAvB1BPDMtAFirBQBgUPBCeypBvaUzoeefhddKZX0bDfSAZ9AEcQwlhViVQwF4FQuhLiRiapVAkhBShY9pqaNYWwHRd9OECTge2Z6mA-aYBsKRTE3tdqoIkHub2ypdp4DAnudM5IzBCiyGuZB2t1CgAAPzTH4D+P8WtUE61AEKI07p2x0ImOOI0YxdrACiWEjGVSQm1OVO40G4MkkoLlAqPumJgkyFCVkLxnkfF+MQGMGIyS8nqA4FMmI9Tel7koZLSOGD0CdNzLJbpDT+lom8b4mwoyb792WfgEoH5U5w0utMUAABqQ5CcOBmHTtAcRszQnNJzM5TUQSGnhKWAM22uyRk-MidErI2DoDOy3iMqpNSgWwD3KC4iHA87cQQPGSpwA4VApFJSdQe5AC8G4AAR2lhgo4F8NkxBuKNWIANUQpJ4DouxeKeFMRpjs31qAXajLcWAApyYliLsroHUNAAAXqwaltKdgMvSji5lrKsXSqZYAHg3AAu+3y7gHBm6CHFWoSVVSuWNMxi8g12IuyPhXnGAc4BYCwF3vONZny6nvCOHCFcFwZHUAxPAeEWyDjOslQa8mu0N5b1gEFYAAaOXACdZ611MhLjGtNWCVMIQIgcGMpcbpVrYCgHDVgzAhkzA7GtDSOoDZC3wAAEJsDcpACsWBMCsXvG4IAA)

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-query@3.34.16/dist/react-query.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.6/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// Adapted from https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview#enough-talk-show-me-some-code-already

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import { default as React, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
// import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery, type UseQueryResult } from 'react-query';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the above import statments
const { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } = React;
const { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } = ReactQuery;

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

async function fetchGitHubRepoData (user: string, repo: string) {
  return (await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}`)).json();
}

function fetchRepoReactQuery () {
  return fetchGitHubRepoData('tannerlinsley', 'react-query');
};

function delay (ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// This one will always be > 2000ms
async function fetchRepoTypeScript () {
  const data = fetchGitHubRepoData('microsoft', 'TypeScript');
  await delay(2000);
  return data;
}

/**
 * Get duration of current query in milliseconds
 * Returns `Infinity` while loading
 */
function useQueryTime (queryKey: string, status: UseQueryResult['status']): number {
  const lastKeyRef = useRef('__initial');
  const [interval, setInterval] = useState<[begin: number, end: number]>([0, Infinity]);

  return useMemo(() => {
    if (lastKeyRef.current !== queryKey) {
      lastKeyRef.current = queryKey;
      setInterval([0, Infinity]);
    }

    const [begin, end] = interval;

    if (begin === 0 && status === 'loading') {
      setInterval(([, end]) => [performance.now(), end]);
    }

    if (!Number.isFinite(end) && ['error', 'success'].includes(status)) {
      setInterval(([begin]) => [begin, performance.now()]);
    }

    return end - begin;
  }, [interval, status, queryKey]);
}

function Example() {
  const [[queryKey, queryFn], setQueryKeyAndFn] = useState<[string, () => Promise<any>]>(['react-query', fetchRepoReactQuery]);

  const { isLoading, error, data, status } = useQuery(queryKey, queryFn);
  const queryTime = useQueryTime(queryKey, status);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Change query after 2 seconds:
    setTimeout(() => setQueryKeyAndFn(['TypeScript', fetchRepoTypeScript]), 2000);
  }, [setQueryKeyAndFn]);

  const queryInfoNode = (
    <div>
      <h2>Query time: {isLoading ? 'still loading' : `${queryTime} ms`}</h2>
    </div>
  );

  if (isLoading) return (<div>{queryInfoNode}'Loading...'</div>);
  if (error) return (<div>{queryInfoNode}'An error has occurred: ' + error.message</div>);

  return (
    <div>
      {queryInfoNode}
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <strong> {data.subscribers_count}</strong>{' '}
      <strong>✨ {data.stargazers_count}</strong>{' '}
      <strong> {data.forks_count}</strong>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Example />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: This works great for an initial fetch, but it will show always the same number if you use `refetch` for updating data.